# 犬 spelled as イッヌ

Tags: katakana, internet-slang

https://twitter.com/tyomateee2/status/1440691228115230731

> イッヌ「ご主人！がんばって！」

In the above dog-related tweet, 犬 seems to be spelled as 'イッヌ' rather than 'イヌ'. Is the presence of 'ッ' a typo or is it a stylistic choice? If it's not a typo, are there circumstances where you should use write ッヌ instead of ンヌ in a word?

Comment: Japanese Wikipedia says [it's an analog of *doggo*](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/DoggoLingo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Japanese equivalent of the word [doge](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/doge) and doggo(thanks to @naruto). It's a slang for a word 犬/イヌ, that was born in famous Japanese BBS, 2ch.

So no, you shouldn't be using this word in normal conversation. You can however, use this word in a tweet like that.

Comment: But why is it イッヌ and not インヌ?

Comment: @istrasci ...But why did you(and, OP) thought インヌ would fit? I mean, I've heard people who are quite old pronounce 犬 like this (not in the sense that the person is using this slang). Maybe it was a kind of accent, because it just simply adds a 促音. インヌ however, is doesn't sound... natural? the fact that you should pronounce more sound is... doesn't make sense? I... I honestly don't know how to describe it.

Comment: @Skye-AT, if you're familiar at all with IPA, could you annotate the difference in pronunciation between イッヌ and インヌ?  That would help to clarify.  I am unfamiliar with small-っ used with the "N" kana, and I do not know what this would indicate if not for a geminate "N" sound, so ッヌ would be functionally equivalent with ンヌ.  But from what you're saying here, the two should be pronounced differently?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi It's completely different. Probably it's much easier to understand by watching the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcFdCRCcc-w) than by teaching with words.

Comment: @Skye-AT, I'm familiar with 促音 as a feature of Japanese.  I am not familiar with 促音 + the "N" kana, and that video doesn't address this at all.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Then I think I can't help you, I really can't understand the idea of 促音+ン kana. The fact that you still think you could use/add "ン" after watching the video and (already) knowing the 促音 is strange to me. I don't mean to be offensive at all, but if your native language doesn't have the concept of 促音-ish sound in your native language, does it seem that way?

Comment: Or, you may got confused by my comment saying "*I've heard people who are quite old pronounce 犬 like this*..."? I meant that old people said イッヌ, not インヌ

Comment: I think I understand now. イッヌ is like i'nu while インヌ is like innu. The small-tsu calls for a brief pause before the next syllable. Putting an ン before an before an n+vowel syllable calls for the n sound to be elongated instead.

Comment: Does the word ネッコ also exist? Just curious

Comment: @SpikedHelmet Yes!

Comment: @kandyman Yes it exists, it's not as popular as イッヌ, though.

Comment: @kandyman The cat version is [ぬこ](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%81%AC%E3%81%93). ネッコ is fairly uncommon.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi ッヌ is simply an invalid combination in standard Japanese, and I think no one can explain how to pronounce イッヌ "properly". No one would complain whether you pronounced it like インヌ or like イ・ヌ. This is internet slang after all, and it became popular exactly because of its silly spelling.

Comment: @Skye-AT, thanks for the reply. By _the “N” kana_, I mean なにぬねの, not ん. In various things I’ve read, 促音 is treated as a kind of lengthening of the consonant value, the consonantal version of 長音符. Consider バッハ, for instance, where the //h// is extended. It sounds like イッヌ is intended differently, more like //iʔnu// with a glottal stop before the //n//.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Ah, now I see what you meant. I think you should know this: There is no other word that's with "-な/に/ぬ/ね/の/ん" that comes with 促音(AFAIK). This is internet slang after all, it's not supposed to be pronounced correctly (as naruto said). So I think there's no way to indicate how to pronounce this with IPA... The most closest expression is "i'nu" as SpikedHelmet indicated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can be called as a stylistic choice, but the 'spelling' イッヌ is  intentional. It is a slang which originated from a (notorious) Japanese website (then) called 2ちゃんねる. [This](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%83%E3%83%8C) explains how it got created.

As such, if you know nothing about the website, it is better to stay away from writing ッヌ.